Microsoft Partner Center Webhooks Implementation
I am currently building a self service portal for our CSP customer , where in they can view their licenses , add new licenses or new products to their tenant , view their Azure subscription usage etc . I was trying to implement webhooks which listens and responds when a subscription change event is triggered, but I can't seem to find any stepwise documentation from microsoft on how to implement . Sadly, there are no developer setting available in my sandbox Partner Center environment ( a newbie when it comes to webhooks ).  Are there any developer setting in Partner Center Portal ? I can't seem to find it or is there a way to enable it ?
If anyone has worked or used it , Do let me know
Thanks
I tried looking for developer setting inside of the Partner Center Portal to configure our endpoint URL or event to test the webhook , But I can't find anything around it .
